# How to set up an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, coordinates

I'm struggling to find the right way to set up an array of waypoints in a 2-dimensional plane. As an example:

Point 1: x= 2.3, y= 4.5

Point 2: x= 3.1, y= 5.0

...

Point 83: x= 25.3, y= 83.1

I'd like to be able to cycle through the array of points (like: for points 10 to 25, move the x-coordinate by 3 to the right), and call off a single point (what are the coordinates of point 42?).

This is really easy in VisualBasic (dim wayPoints (100,2) as Double) , but having gone through the swift documentation I'm getting nowhere. The syntax of arrays seems to be much more complicated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a struct for this.

```
struct Point {
    var x: Double = 0.0
    var y: Double = 0.0
}

// Create an instance of the point struct
var myPoint = Point(x: 2.5, y: 6.7)

// You can also create an array of Point structs
var points: [Point] = [Point(x: 3.4, y: 8.5)]
```

You can cycle through the array and make any changes you want. As [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) pointed out, you cannot modify a `struct` directly in a `for` loop, so you need to access the array by indexes. For example:

```
for index in points.indices {
    points[index].x += 30 // This adds 30 to the x coordinate of each point in the array
}
```

You can access any point in the array with a subscript index.

```
var selectedPoint = points[4] // This returns a single Point object
```

You can also make a new array using a range if you want.

```
var rangeOfPoints = points[0...4] // This returns a new array of Points with 5 items
```

Comment: Can I then access the information in points with points[i], where i is some integer? And if I only want the x-coordinate, do I write: let xCoord = points(i).x ? Sorry about the confusion in the brackets, not even sure which one I should use.

Comment: @Bathan Yes that's right. You can use an integer to get any point in the array, or a range to make a new array with a range of the points. The coordinates can be accessed with dot syntax exactly like you have done.

Comment: You are treating a struct like a class. **"You can use a struct for this. You can cycle through the array and make any changes you want."** No you can't. Xcode should not even compile it. `Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'point' is a 'let' constant`

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry I should have made those last two arrays var instead of let. You can change var properties of a var struct, right? I admit I’m more used to classes. Regarding CGPoint, that would definitely make sense if it was graphics coordinates, but he might need a type to represent coordinates for some other abstraction as well.

Comment: I am talking about the for loop. declaring `var myPoint` won't make a difference.

Comment: @LeoDabus Ah yes of course. It will work if accessed by index though right. I’ll change it.

Comment: yes `for index in points.indices {
    points[index].x += 30
}`

Comment: use the collection indices. Not all collections starts from 0

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I was not aware of how to use a collections indices like that. This has been educational!

Comment: @LeoDabus Good idea - they’re two different things.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have changed the x and y values as well, to make it more distinct.